# Cannot load ODBC DLLs in Delphi2007 on Win7 64bit when running inside IDE

Tags: delphi, windows-7, 64-bit, odbc, syswow64

Can anyone help with this.

I'm using Delphi2007 December update.

I'm trying to connect to a Gupta database through ODBC and get the error message: The specified module could not be found. C:\Windows\System32\c2gup15.dll.

The DLLs are 32 bit and are found in c:\Windows\SysWow64 as they should be.

When running my compiled program standalone (not inside Delphi) I have no problems.

On XP (my other machine) running within Delphi IDE gives no problems.

All other ways of connecting (like Excel) through this ODBC-driver works perfect.

I'm having this problem both with ODBCExpress and AnyDac.

As I have understood it: When running a 32 bit app in Win7 64 bit windows should automatically use SysWow64 instead of System32.

Does Delphi2007 in some way ruin or override this?

Any suggestions how to solve it? (It's not easy developing software when you can't use your debugger)

Comment: 1) Do you have any Delphi IDE addons installed ? If yes, then try first to remove / disable them. 2) In general you can use Delphi IDE debugger to debug Delphi IDE. Run second Delphi instance, then use Run -> Attach to process, and see what happens. 3) Run regedit and choose HKLM\Software\ Wow6432Node\ODBC\ ODBCINST.INI, then Gupta ODBC driver and check the DLL paths. 4) You can post also on da-soft forum, then our technical support will respond.

Comment: The registry value "Driver" points to C:\Windows\System32. Changing this to C:\Windows\SysWow64 does not give a better result. Only telling me that the module was not found in C:\Windows\SysWow64.

Comment: But is this DLL in SysWOW64 ?

Comment: Problem solved.

Using Process Monitor from SysInternals I found that Gupta DLL c2bas15.dll was dependent of a DLL called sqlwntm.dll and this was not found when running inside of Delphi. Environment variable Path on the computer had a reference to where the DLL was found but due to some snag in Delphi, environment variable Path there didn’t have it. Added an override it to Delphis local copy of machine Path and it all worked.

As said before, this was never a problem when running Delphi2007 on XP 32 bit.

Thanks to da-soft for trying to help out.

Comment: When the system permits, you can add your solution as an answer.

Comment: Agreed. Answer your own question!